# Complicated Oracle Query not returning the correct information

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

Here is a more direct part of the question. There is something wrong with the following query. It returns every ip_address ever used by the customer, instead of filtering it for the current month. When deallocation_date is null or between the dates is the only ip addresses it needs to select. The query directly below here is my attempt at doing that with a correlated sub query using if it exist within these conditions count, and sum for those ip addresses. However below I show there are only 29 Ip addresses with deallocation_date = null and deallocated between those dates because for this customer the max deallocation date is in august. I know its selecting all the ip's ever assigned the customer. Please help me fix the sub query to return the right data. I'm just not that great with SQL to know where my mistake is. I know it has something to do with the way I'm using or.

I also know as it was pointed out that it will only select until 00:00:00 on the last day of the month and for now I'm ok with that I can fix that later. I need it to return right data. As I know for this customer there have been no deallocations for this month.

The trouble part is :

and (trunc(d.deallocation_date) between to_date(:run_date) and last_day(:run_date) or f.deallocation_date is null))

because that should filter the IP's to 29 no matter what is in the ip_address_usages table, but the count is staying at 57 which means its selecting them all.

```
set pagesize 2000
set linesize 300
break on report on customer_name skip 1
compute sum label Total of GigaBytes_Sent GigaBytes_Received IPS_IN_USE on customer_name
compute sum label Grand-Total of GigaBytes_Sent GigaBytes_Received IPS_IN_USE on REPORT
column GigaBytes_Sent format 999,999,999,999.99
column GigaBytes_Received format 999,999,999,999.99

select customer_name,
       substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
       decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name) vm_display_name,
       sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Sent,
       sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Received,
       count(unique e.ip_address_id) IPS_IN_USE
  from customers a,
       vm_groups b, 
       vms c, 
       vm_ip_address_histories d, 
       ip_address_usages e
 where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
   and b.vm_group_id=c.vm_group_id
   and c.vm_id=d.vm_id
   and d.ip_address_id=e.ip_address_id
   and trunc(e.datetime) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)
   and exists (select f.deallocation_date 
                   from vm_ip_address_histories f 
                   where f.vm_id = d.vm_id 
                   and (trunc(d.deallocation_date) between to_date(:run_date) and last_day(:run_date) or f.deallocation_date is null))
   and inactive = 'N'
   and a.customer_id = 30
--   and (bytes_sent > 0 or bytes_received > 0)
 group by customer_name,
       substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100),
       decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name)
 order by 1,2,3
/
```

I'm trying to summarize bytes sent and recieved from ip_address_usages table, 
while counting the distinct ip_address_id's that belong to a customer between 
the first and last day of the month that have a deallocation date of null, 
or a value that falls between the first and last day of the month. 
When ever I run the first query below it will return the wrong number of IP addresses associated with the customer.

I can obviously see its not accounting for the last and first day of the month, 
however when I add that it throws off teh summarization as I show below.
I'm trying to make it so the summarization and ip account are correct.

Here are the table relations, I only included the relevant ones with descriptions.

```
    Customers > VM_Groups  
    VM_Groups > VMS 
    VMS > VM_IP_ADDRESS_HISTORIES 
    VM_IP_ADDRESS_HISTORIES > IP_ADDRESSES by ip_address_id, 
    IP_ADDRESSES > IP_ADDRESS_USAGES "this is where bytes sent and received is" relates to IP_ADDRESSES by ip_address_id
```

I masked information for security concerns but you don't need it to answer the question:

returned values from the first query that is wrong the count is 57 and not 29:

```
    variable run_date varchar2(30)
    exec :run_date := to_date('1-oct-14')

    set pagesize 2000
    set linesize 300
    break on report on customer_name skip 1
    compute sum label Total of GigaBytes_Sent GigaBytes_Received IPS_IN_USE on customer_name
    compute sum label Grand-Total of GigaBytes_Sent GigaBytes_Received IPS_IN_USE on REPORT
    column GigaBytes_Sent format 999,999,999,999.99
    column GigaBytes_Received format 999,999,999,999.99

    select customer_name,
           substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
           decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name) vm_display_name,
           sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Sent,
           sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Received,
           count(unique e.ip_address_id) IPS_IN_USE
      from customers a,
           vm_groups b, 
           vms c, 
           vm_ip_address_histories d, 
           ip_address_usages e
     where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
       and b.vm_group_id=c.vm_group_id
       and c.vm_id=d.vm_id
       and d.ip_address_id=e.ip_address_id
       and trunc(e.datetime) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)
       and inactive = 'N'
       and a.customer_id = 30
    --   and (bytes_sent > 0 or bytes_received > 0)
     group by customer_name,
           substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100),
           decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name)
     order by 1,2,3
    /


    CUSTOMER_NAME              VM_NAME                                                  VM_DISPLAY_NAME         GIGABYTES_SENT  GIGABYTES_RECEIVED IPS_IN_USE
    ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------- ----------
    mask/masked        mask/masked                                                                                  198.59                    168.57            29
                       mask/masked                                                                                  43.35                      33.95            19
                       mask/masked                                                                                  164.04                    135.86             9
    ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************     
    Total                                                                                       405.98                    338.38            57

    set pagesize 2000
    set linesize 300
    break on report on customer_name skip 1
    compute sum label Total of GigaBytes_Sent GigaBytes_Received IPS_IN_USE on customer_name
    compute sum label Grand-Total of GigaBytes_Sent GigaBytes_Received IPS_IN_USE on REPORT
    column GigaBytes_Sent format 999,999,999,999.99
    column GigaBytes_Received format 999,999,999,999.99

    select customer_name,
           substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
           decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name) vm_display_name,
           sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Sent,
           sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Received,
           count(unique e.ip_address_id) IPS_IN_USE
      from customers a,
           vm_groups b, 
           vms c, 
           vm_ip_address_histories d, 
           ip_address_usages e
     where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
       and b.vm_group_id=c.vm_group_id
       and c.vm_id=d.vm_id
       and d.ip_address_id=e.ip_address_id
       and trunc(e.datetime) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)
       and (d.deallocation_date is null or d.deallocation_date between to_date(:run_date) and last_day(:run_date))
       and inactive = 'N'
       and a.customer_id =30
    --   and (bytes_sent > 0 or bytes_received > 0)
     group by customer_name,
           substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100),
           decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name)
     order by 1,2,3
    /

    CUSTOMER_NAME              VM_NAME                                                  VM_DISPLAY_NAME         GIGABYTES_SENT  GIGABYTES_RECEIVED IPS_IN_USE
    ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------- ----------
    mask/masked        mask/masked                                                                                  .00                          .01              8
                       mask/masked                                                                                  43.35                      33.95             18
                       mask/masked                                                                                  .00                          .01              3
    ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************                                                                 
    Total                                                                                       43.35                        33.97          29

    select max(deallocation_date) 
    from vm_ip_address_histories a, 
    vms b, vm_groups c, 
    customers d 
    where a.vm_id = b.vm_id 
    and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id 
    and c.customer_id = d.customer_id 
    and d.customer_id = 30
    /

    MAX(DEALLOCATION_DATE)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    04-AUG-14 06.04.30.000000 PM


    select distinct e.ip_address, 
    a.customer_name,
    c.vm_id, 
    d.allocation_date, 
    d.deallocation_date
    from customers a, 
    vm_groups b, 
    vms c, 
    vm_ip_address_histories d, 
    ip_addresses e 
    where a.customer_id=30
    and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
    and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
    and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
    and exists (select * from vm_ip_address_histories where d.deallocation_date is null or trunc(d.deallocation_date) >= to_date('1-oct-14') )
    /

      2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17  
    IP_ADDRESS           CUSTOMER_NAME               VM_ID ALLOCATION_DATE                                 DEALLOCATION_DATE
    -------------------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.58.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 30-JUL-14 03.18.41.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 04.43.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.43.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.43.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                1586 26-FEB-14 10.48.18.000000 AM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 28-JUN-14 12.45.22.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 21-JUN-14 01.29.23.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 04.58.48.000000 PM

    IP_ADDRESS           CUSTOMER_NAME               VM_ID ALLOCATION_DATE                                 DEALLOCATION_DATE
    -------------------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.58.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.43.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 20-FEB-14 04.47.33.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 04.13.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.58.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 04.43.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                1586 17-JUN-14 02.13.47.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 04-AUG-14 06.04.30.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                1586 25-FEB-14 05.03.12.000000 PM

    IP_ADDRESS           CUSTOMER_NAME               VM_ID ALLOCATION_DATE                                 DEALLOCATION_DATE
    -------------------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------select customer_name,
       substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
       decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name) vm_display_name,
       sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Sent,
       sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Received,
       count(unique e.ip_address_id) IPS_IN_USE
  from customers a,
       vm_groups b, 
       vms c, 
       vm_ip_address_histories d, 
       ip_address_usages e
 where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
   and b.vm_group_id=c.vm_group_id
   and c.vm_id=d.vm_id
   and d.ip_address_id=e.ip_address_id
   and trunc(e.datetime) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)
   and exists (select * from vm_ip_address_histories f where deallocation_date is null or trunc(deallocation_date) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date) )
   and inactive = 'N'
   and a.customer_id = 30
--   and (bytes_sent > 0 or bytes_received > 0)
 group by customer_name,
       substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100),
       decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name)
 order by 1,2,3
------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX                 365 17-JAN-14 03.02.25.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 04.13.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 03.43.48.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 28-JUN-14 12.30.23.000000 PM
    XXXXXXXX             XXXXXXXXX               27374 17-JUN-14 04.43.48.000000 PM

    29 rows selected.




    select distinct e.ip_address
    from customers a, 
    vm_groups b, 
    vms c, 
    vm_ip_address_histories d, 
    ip_addresses e 
    where a.customer_id=30
    and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
    and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
    and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
    and (d.deallocation_date is null or d.deallocation_date between to_date('01-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('31-10-2014 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
    /  

    IP_ADDRESS
    --------------------------------
    MASKED FOR SECURITY

    29 rows selected.



    select count(distinct e.ip_address)
    from customers a, 
    vm_groups b, 
    vms c, 
    vm_ip_address_histories d, 
    ip_addresses e 
    where a.customer_id=30
    and a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
    and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
    and d.ip_address_id = e.ip_address_id
    and (d.deallocation_date is null or d.deallocation_date between to_date('01-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('31-10-2014 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
    /

    COUNT(DISTINCTE.IP_ADDRESS)
    ---------------------------
                 29
```

so I wrote another query using a correlated sub query to try and filter out only the ip's allocated and deallocated within the range but it still returned 57 but correct usage data. Now obviously there are only 29 as I have show above quite adequately. Thus, its something in my query. Please look and tell me whats wrong with the query.

```
    select customer_name,
           substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
           decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name) vm_display_name,
           sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Sent,
           sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Received,
           count(unique e.ip_address_id) IPS_IN_USE
      from customers a,
           vm_groups b, 
           vms c, 
           vm_ip_address_histories d, 
           ip_address_usages e
     where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
       and b.vm_group_id=c.vm_group_id
       and c.vm_id=d.vm_id
       and d.ip_address_id=e.ip_address_id
       and trunc(e.datetime) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)
       and exists (select * from vm_ip_address_histories f where deallocation_date is null or trunc(deallocation_date) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date) )
       and inactive = 'N'
       and a.customer_id = 30
    --   and (bytes_sent > 0 or bytes_received > 0)
     group by customer_name,
           substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100),
           decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name)
     order by 1,2,3
```

basically with this query I want it to only summarize and count when it exist within the range of the correlated subquery

same thing here

```
select customer_name,
       substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100) vm_name,
       decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name) vm_display_name,
       sum(bytes_sent)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Sent,
       sum(bytes_received)*1.8/power(10,9) GigaBytes_Received,
       count(unique e.ip_address_id) IPS_IN_USE
  from customers a,
       vm_groups b, 
       vms c, 
       vm_ip_address_histories d, 
       ip_address_usages e
 where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
   and b.vm_group_id=c.vm_group_id
   and c.vm_id=d.vm_id
   and d.ip_address_id=e.ip_address_id
   and trunc(e.datetime) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)
   and exists (select f.deallocation_date from vm_ip_address_histories f where f.vm_id = d.vm_id and (f.deallocation_date is null or trunc(f.deallocation_date) between :run_date and last_day(:run_date)) )
   and inactive = 'N'
   and a.customer_id = 30
--   and (bytes_sent > 0 or bytes_received > 0)
 group by customer_name,
       substr(decode(vcd_managed,'Y',vm_name,'N',vm_group_name || ' ' || vm_display_name),1,100),
       decode(vcd_managed,'Y',null,'N',vm_display_name)
 order by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Can you put together a reproducible test case (i.e. something we can run in our system which creates the tables you need, populates some dummy data, and shows us the expected results)?  Otherwise, it's going to be nearly impossible for anyone else to guess at where your problem lies.

Comment: If I can get the time to do it I will do it tonight. Thanks for taking the time to look. Thats why I included so much data was in the hopes that someone could see what im not seeing, or adjust my query. basically its looking at all the ip's ever in the vm_ip_address_histories table and ignoring deallocation date, but when I set it to look at that it throws my usage data off, I expect it to decrease a bit because it wont associate the bad IP's with the customer but its so far off I know its wrong.\

Comment: Im adding some more data now that might help.

Comment: Can you please look at the top part of the question now and just help me with the subquery @JustinCave

Comment: I suggest you qualify column names with their table name at every point in the query, including any subselects.

Answer (score 0):

The LAST_DAY function returns the date of the last day of the month provided as input, but it is also includes the time component of date you provided, so your clause

```
    d.deallocation_date between to_date(:run_date) and last_day(:run_date))
```

should probably be

```
   truncate(d.deallocation_date) between to_date(:run_date) and last_day(:run_date))
```

Your code sets :run_date to a varchar field without a time component, so last_day(:run_date) will be at 00:00:00, and so if d.deallocation_date has a time later than then, it won't get selected.

```
SQL> variable run_date varchar2(30)
SQL> exec :run_date := to_date('1-oct-14')

SQL>  select to_char(to_date(:run_date), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as first_of_month,
2*     to_char(last_day(to_date(:run_date)), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as last_of_month from dual;

FIRST_OF_MONTH      LAST_OF_MONTH
------------------- -------------------
2014-10-01 00:00:00 2014-10-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: I see that but there is something wrong with my query, its not actually filtering the deallocation dates it just keeps selecting all

Comment: Can you please look at the top part of the question now and just help me with the subquery @Mark Stewart

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry, @Grant.  I'm stumped now too!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to this part:

```
(trunc(d.deallocation_date) between to_date(:run_date) and last_day(:run_date) 
or f.deallocation_date is null))
```

Should you be using `deallocation_date` from the same table on both sides of the `or`?

Comment: well i'm trying to find if it has a deallocation date between the dates or if its null.